# How can I provide Metadata from my WCF service for consumption in Breeze

Tags: wcf, breeze, single-page-application

I am trying to adapt an existing WebApi/MVC4 app to use Breeze lookups.

Currently I retrieve my DTOs via

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<ThingDto> GetThings()
    {

        var channelFactory = ThingServiceConfiguration.CreateChannelFactory();
        _serviceFactory = () => new WcfProxy<IThingService>(channelFactory.CreateChannel());

        var client = _serviceFactory();

        IQueryable<ThingDto> result = client.Execute(p => p.GetThings()).OrderBy(x => x.Name).AsQueryable();

        return result;
    }
```

I'm not sure how I implement this method Metadata()

```
 public string Metadata()
 {
      //normally something like this if using a EF DataContext
      // return _someContextProvider.Context.Things;

 }
```

How I setup the WCF config

```
public class ThingServiceConfiguration
{
    const string AppSettingKey = "ThingServiceUrl";

    public static ChannelFactory<IThingService> CreateChannelFactory()
    {
       // var serviceUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppSettingKey];
        var serviceUrl = "http://localhost:86/ThingService.svc";
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None)
        {
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 200000000,
            SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
            ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)
        };
        var address = new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl);
        return new ChannelFactory<IThingService>(binding, address);
    }
}
```

Could this metadata be provided with the WCF call into the Metadata() property (by providing arguments through BasicHttpBinding ?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can return Breeze 'native' metadata simply by returning the metadata in json form.  Something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public String Metadata() {
  var folder = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "App_Data");
  // metadata.json is the name of a file containing your metadata - pick any file name you like.
  var fileName = Path.Combine(folder, "metadata.json");
  var jsonMetadata = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
  return jsonMetadata;
}
```

where the syntax of the metadata file is described here: [Breeze metadata format](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-metadata-format).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm ok with returning a string of json but I'm really interested in how I would extract this metadata.json from WCF. I imagine this being a change to wcf configuration to expose MEX but I'm unsure of how to do that.